# Daemoninsing a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, daemon

I have a rake task which runs mailman under the rails environment.

I'd like to ensure that rake task is always running via a daemon.

My rake task is `rake incoming_mail`

How would I go about daemonising that?

Comment: Are you using linux or osx? What kind of features do you want this daemon to have?

Comment: `daemon stop` and `daemon start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on linux you could consider using start-stop-daemon.

`start-stop-daemon -S --pidfile /var/run/incoming_mail.pid -u rails_user -d /path/to/your/rails/app -b -a "rake incoming_mail"`

To later gracefully kill the process you can use most of the arguments but replace -S with -K.

As always you can find more information on start-stop-daemon by reading the man pages.

Answer (score 4):

In linux in order to run a process in background, you can add & to the end of command. So

rake incoming_mail &

should probably do the jobs for you.

Comment: how can I make sure the rake task is running once the rails app has been started.

Comment: This solution just runs it in the background, which is fine, until you want to make sure the thing is up, and working.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby 1.9+, you could use [Process.daemon](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-daemon). There's also a solution for Ruby < 1.9: http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766093-daemon-processes-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

If it's a docker image then surely it must be linux so,

```
rake incoming_mail &
```

should do the job by login into the pod and running rake task

Apart from this, put

`Rails.logger.info` in your code so the logs will be pushed to application log file OR

GCloud Stackdriver or any logging framework.